# How to create a local branch from an existing remote branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

I want to create a branch from an existing remote branch (let's say remote-A) and then commit the changes to the repository.

I have used the below commands to create a local branch from the existing remote-A

```
$git checkout remote-A

git branch
master
* remote-A
```

Now I have created local-B from Remote A using the below commands

```
git branch local-B
git checkout local-B
```

How do I make sure the changes I have on local-B are on top of remote-A so that when I push local-B to the remote repo, the changes are on top of remote-A?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you want to create branch on base of remote-A, make changes on it and then push them on remote-A?

```
git checkout -b remote-A
git pull origin remote-A
git checkout -b remote-B
```

make changes on remote-B

```
 git commit -a -m 'describe changes on remote-B branch'

 git checkout remote-A  
 git merge remote-B  
 git push origin remote-A
```

Comment: Nowadays, `git checkout feature/A` will set up a new branch tracking remote `origin/feature/A`, unless `feature/A` already exists. You can also do this explicitly with `git checkout -b feature/A --track origin/feature/A`.

Answer (score 210):

Old post, still I'd like to add what I do.

```
1. git remote add <remote_name> <repo_url>
2. git fetch <remote_name>
3. git checkout -b <new_branch_name> <remote_name>/<remote_branch_name>
```

This series of commands will

1. create a new remote,
2. fetch it into your local so your local git knows about its branches and all,
3. create a new branch from the remote branch and checkout to that.

Now if you want to publish this new local branch to your remote and set the upstream url also

`git push origin +<new_branch_name>`

Also, if only taking in remote changes was your requirement and remote already exists in your local, you could have done, instead of step 2 and 3,

```
git pull --rebase <remote_name> <remote_branch_name>
```

and then opted for
`git mergetool` (needs configurations separately) in case of any conflicts, and follow console instructions from git.

Comment: I think the commands I added will help you. Or did I misunderstand anything from your statement? I normally fetch the remote, create a branch out of it, work on it, push changes to my origin remote, raise PR to main repo and once it gets merged, I delete the feature branch. This helps me segregate many tasks and keep the tree clean.

Comment: `git checkout -b <new_branch_name> <remote_name>/<remote_branch_name>` was the command I was trying to find. Nothing more. I removed the original statement, since it seems to have been confusing.

Comment: You can use `-t` to create the local branch with same name to save a bit of typing - `git checkout -t <remote_server>/<remote_branch>`

Comment: On step 3 use `--no-track` if you don't want your new branch to track the remote one.

Comment: @xploreraj Your answer is what I was looking for, thanks alot.

Comment: @xploreraj, Good Answer. Never loosing track, where branch came from. Thanks.

Comment: Why I got this error `fatal: 'orgin/alex/ITCAML-1315' is not a commit and a branch 'ITCAML-1315' cannot be created from it`

Answer (score 92):

This should work:

`git checkout --track origin/<REMOTE_BRANCH_NAME>`

Comment: If you want to give a specific name to the new branch: `git checkout -b master-copy --track origin/master`, replace `master-copy` with whatever you wish.

Comment: Or `git checkout -t origin/<REMOTE_BRANCH_NAME>`

Comment: this short one line of command is really work... ! and yet easy to understand.

Comment: I found [this article](https://thelinuxcode.com/create-local-branch-from-an-existing-remote-branch/) useful for understanding this answer (also added to Wayback Machine)

Answer (score 21):

I wanted to create a new local tracking branch from a remote git branch with a different name.

So I used this command:

`git checkout -b <new_branch_name> --track <remote_name>/<remote_branch_name>`

Example:

`git checkout -b local-A --track origin/remote-A`

I saw it in multiple comments to the above answers, but it's good to have it in the first sight.

Tracking branches are local branches that have a direct relationship to a remote branch. If you're on a tracking branch and type git pull, Git automatically knows which server to fetch from and which branch to merge in.

Comment: It is efficient to do both checkout and track in a single command - this worked for me too.

Answer (score 16):

First we need to fetch the remote branch using

```
git fetch origin <remote-branch>
```

Then just create a new local branch to track the remote branch

```
git checkout -b <local-branch> origin/<remote-branch>
```

Replace `origin` with your remote name.

Comment: Important to note this is only applicable after you have created a branch manually on your remote repo first either through git command or GUI.

Answer (score 8):

Since the introduction of `git switch` in version 2.23:

```
git switch -c <new-branch> <start-point>
```

Where `<start-point>` is your remote branch, for example `origin/main`.

In case you want to simply create a local branch from a remote one, for example from `origin/remote-branch` you can simply run:

```
git switch remote-branch
```

It will create a new local branch from the remote one.

Comment: Finally nice syntax to what is done frequently without million commands and million parameters. Someone should give a prize to git UI developer, finally.

Comment: What's the difference between having the -c and not?  I'm trying to run these commands in a script and I want it to create a local branch if it doesn't exist but if it does, then I just want it to switch to it.

Comment: @tzg You migh want to look at -C then, the capital C that is.

Answer (score 6):

First download all your remote branches by :

```
git fetch
```

then create a local branch from it:

```
git checkout -b local_branch_name origin/remote_branch_name
```

Comment: I have a grievance with git that I have to look up and do these steps. The tool should be able to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score -5):

To make sure your changes are on top, you must not pull from remote. you must fetch and rebase. il will be something like this:

```
fetch->stash->rebase->stash pop->commit->push
```

Comment: From git documentation: "git pull --rebase" is a shorthand for "git fetch" followed by "git rebase". See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull